# DllNotFoundException error when loading C++ DLL

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to use C++ DLL in Unity, but I am prompted with “DllNotFoundException” error in Unity.I tried the method of others on the network, it didn't work for me.

I tried the method on Unity's official website, but it didn't work.
https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/Manual/NativePlugins.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForDesktop.html
Running the SimplestPluginExample Demo of Unity's official website is also prompted with “DllNotFoundException” error in Unity.

```
extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport) AddTwoIntegers(int a, int b) 
{
    return a + b;
}
```

```
put the MyDLL.dll in Assets/Plugins
```

```
[DllImport("MyDLL")]
private static extern int AddTwoIntegers(int a, int b);
void Start ()
{
    Debug.Log(AddTwoIntegers(2, 3)); 
}
```

```
DllNotFoundException: MyDLL
```

Comment: put your DLL in %window% or %windows%\system, and retry.
If it's works, then the search path or location file is wrong.

Comment: Is the DLL on the [windows search path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order)? Is it compiled for the same architecture as your unity process? (you cannot match 64-bit and 32-bit DLLs in the same process) Does procmon.exe give you any clues about the result of the underlying `LoadLibrary` call? The [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForDesktop.html) for bundling native plugins suggests putting 32-bit plugins into `Assets/Plugins/x86` and 64-bit plugins into `Assets/Plugins/x86_64` to avoid mixing them up.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with extension. And  put importing dll(MyDLL.dll) in output path of the function Caller project.

```
 [DllImport("MyDLL.dll")]
 private static extern int AddTwoIntegers(int a, int b);
 void Start ()
 {
    Debug.Log(AddTwoIntegers(2, 3)); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.My system is 64 bit.I used VS to create 64-bit DLLs.This dll in my Unity is correct,not error tip.